# Motion of a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

If we consider the defination of centre of mass as a point in a system through which if line of force passes the system undergoes pure translational motion. So can we logically deduce from here that centre of mass of a rigid body is that point which moves as if the required force is given to a single particle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.  For pure translational motion, you can treat a rigid body as a point mass.

This breaks down however if you want to consider e.g. rotations, anything involving the volume / surface area (e.g. air resistance) etc, so be sure to check that the problem allows for this first (and in many simple cases it will).

Comment: I know that we can logically deduce the later defination from the former as both are correct but I wanted to know the logic by which we can deduce that . This is basically what I have asked